# ruby on rails - thin - HTTP GET URL > 1024

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, rack, thin

When I use an URL bigger than 1024 appear this in the console of the rails server.

---

```
Invalid request: HTTP element REQUEST_PATH is longer than the 1024 allowed length.
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (r
equired)>'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>
'
        bin/rails:4:in `require'
        bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

---

Can I rescue this exception?

Comment: Why do you have such a long GET url in the first place?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/687142 ?

Comment: it´s only 4 fun. I´m learning Sinatra & RoR. During the learning process I am doing a lot of test